# Parent and Child not staying in sync in Angular 17

Tags: angular, input, output

I am working with Angular 17 and using @Input and @Output to sync between Parent and Child.  The problem is that the syncing is not consistent between the 2. (See attached screen shot).  At some point the sync fails and afterward, the child appears to remain 1 record behind the parent.  For example, in the screen shot a failure has occurred and "Apartment Owners" failed to load.  When the next selection is made in the dropdown, "Apartment Owners" will load in child, with the child remaining 1 step behind the parent with each new selection.

What am I missing?  I have tried to manually update the child by emitting an event, but that did not work either.

Thanks!

```
  async loadAccount(accountID: string) {
this.accountsService.GetAccount(accountID).subscribe((response: Account) => {
  this.page.data.account = response;
  this.onPageUpdate.emit(this.page);   
});
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem.  My mistake was using **onChangeSelected** which occurs on the mat-option element.  onChangeSelected is for cases when multiselect is used and will fire multiple times.   The solution was to use **selectionChange on the mat-select element**.  My html now looks like this:

```
    <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #AccountLookup placeholder="**Company **" (selectionChange)="loadAccount($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let account of page.accountList| accountLookupFilter: page.selectedAccountStatus"
      [ngClass]="account.statusCode == 2 ? 'alert-error' : 'alert-success'" [value]="account.value">
      {{ account.label }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

@Naren Murali  - Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach, create an object on the parent and pass it as an `@Input` property to the child like below

export class ParentComponent {
nestedObj: any = { ngModelValue: 'test';
...

Then on the child receive this property

export class ChildComponent {
@Input() nestedObj!: any;

On the child component HTML, you can do

```
...
<input [(ngModel)]="nestedObj.ngModelValue"/>
...
```

Due to principle of objects and array being passed references, since both parent and child share the same reference, without `@Output` the data between the two components will be in sync, thereby solving your issue!

---

Please store the property in a service and then using getter and setter show the values, so that both will always be in sync

```
...
constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

get showProperty() {
    return this.testService.showProperty;
}
set showProperty(value: any) {
    this.testService.showProperty = value;
}
...
```

If you have this code in both components you can use the same on the html of the components!

Comment: I originally used a service but read online that Input and Output were the preferred method due to leakage in services.

Comment: @zBestData On destroy of the parent component reset the property, that will solve the leakage issue!

Comment: @zBestData updated my answer with an alternative approach using only `@Input()`